# Using GitHub for code rebasing and creating multiple branches for different environments like QA and Production

Tags: git, gitlab

Currently we have a GitHub Repository and we have only One branch master. We are doing all the changes to this branch only while development.

What we need for now is we want to create two more branches. First is for QA and the second is for Production. Once the developer completed with his development then entire master branch code is to be moved from master to QA.

Once QA completed the entire testing then the QA code is to be moved from QA to Production.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read some documentation on git in order to get a better understanding of how it works.

I recommend the Pro Git book, which is available for free here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Read the first three chapters and you should be good to go.